# Strong password generator with symbols that user definies

Tags: java, generator

I've created program like in the title. Actually I know I could use regex to create pattern and then do some actions from it, but I think my code is clear enough (at least for me :P). There is a little thing to correct which is InputMismatch exception that isn't handled. What do you think about my code?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class PasswordGenerator {
    //arrays with optional symbols
    private final char [] symbols = {'~', '`', '!', '@', '#' , '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '_', '-', '=', '+',
            '[', '{', ']', '}', '\\', '|', ';', ':', '\'', '"', ',', '<', '.', '>', '/', '?'};

    private final char [] lowerCaseChars = {'a' , 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o',
            'p', 'q' , 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y' , 'z'};

    private final char [] upperCaseChars = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O',
            'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'};

    private final char [] numbers = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};

    //methods asking about external symbols
    private static boolean wantsSymbols(String kind, String example) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Do you want " + kind + " in password like " + example + "?(Y/N) ");
        char in = input.next().charAt(0);
        return in == 'Y' || in == 'y';
    }

    //return random value from specified array
    private static char randValue(char[] arr) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        return arr[rand.nextInt(arr.length)];
    }

    //combine the random values
    private static char[] combineRandomValues(int length, char[] array) {
        char [] returnedArray = new char[length];
        for(int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
            returnedArray[i] = randValue(array);
        }
        return returnedArray;
    }

    //combine arrays
    private static char[] combineArrays(char[]arr1, char[]arr2, char[]arr3, char[]arr4) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if(arr1.length > 0)
            sb.append(arr1);
        if(arr2.length > 0)
            sb.append(arr2);
        if(arr3.length > 0)
            sb.append(arr3);
        if(arr4.length > 0)
            sb.append(arr4);
        return sb.toString().toCharArray();
    }

    //from long array take random value
    private static char pickRandomValuesFromLongArray(char[] longArray) {
        int randomNumber = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, longArray.length);
        return longArray[randomNumber];
    }

    private static String generatePassword(boolean inclSymbols, boolean inclLower,
                                           boolean inclUpper, boolean inclNumbers, int length) {
        //created object to use the arrays with values
        PasswordGenerator obj = new PasswordGenerator();

        //using string builder to create password
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        //arrays for random values
        char [] sArray = new char[0];
        char [] lArray = new char[0];
        char [] uArray = new char[0];
        char [] nArray = new char[0];

        //take first letters of bool
        char symbolsBool = String.valueOf(inclSymbols).toLowerCase().charAt(0);
        char lowerBool = String.valueOf(inclLower).toLowerCase().charAt(0);
        char upperBool = String.valueOf(inclUpper).toLowerCase().charAt(0);
        char numbersBool = String.valueOf(inclNumbers).toLowerCase().charAt(0);

        if(!inclLower && !inclNumbers && !inclUpper && !inclSymbols) {
            System.out.println("You've to at least include one type of symbol");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        if(symbolsBool == 't') {
            sArray = combineRandomValues(length, obj.symbols);
        }
        if(lowerBool == 't') {
            lArray = combineRandomValues(length, obj.lowerCaseChars);
        }
        if(upperBool == 't') {
            uArray = combineRandomValues(length, obj.upperCaseChars);
        }
        if(numbersBool == 't') {
            nArray = combineRandomValues(length, obj.numbers);
        }

        //combine array 4 arrays from before
        char[] combinedArray = combineArrays(sArray, lArray, uArray, nArray);

        for(int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
            sb.append(pickRandomValuesFromLongArray(combinedArray));

        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int lengthOfPass;
        //variables specifying the complexity of password
        boolean inclSymbols, inclLowercaseChars, inclUppercaseChars, inclNumbers;

        while (true) {
            System.out.print("Password length from 6 to 128: ");
            lengthOfPass = input.nextInt();
            if (lengthOfPass >= 6 && lengthOfPass <= 128) {
                break;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Try again");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        //questions about symbols
        inclSymbols = wantsSymbols("symbols", "$,#,@ etc.");
        //lowercaseCharacters
        inclLowercaseChars = wantsSymbols("lowercase characters", "a,b,c...");
        //uppercaseCharacters
        inclUppercaseChars = wantsSymbols("uppercase characters", "A,B,C...");
        //numbers
        inclNumbers = wantsSymbols("numbers", "0,1,2,3...");

        //initialize and output password
        String password = generatePassword(inclSymbols, inclLowercaseChars, inclUppercaseChars, inclNumbers, lengthOfPass);
        System.out.printf("\n%s", password);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Also I know that I don't hold same structure (e.g. char [] ... and char[] ...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program is not bad. So, please don't see my comments as criticism, but as hints for improvement.

### Syntax

With

```
    if(arr1.length > 0)
        sb.append(arr1);
```

it's much too easy to mistakenly add another line as in

```
    if(arr1.length > 0)
        sb.append(arr1);
        haveAppended = true;
```

which seems to add the line to the conditional part, but in fact sets the variable unconditionally.

I'd prefer to see

```
    if(arr1.length > 0) {
        sb.append(arr1);
    }
```

to avoid that risk.

Otherwise: your indentation is fine, I'd only look at a more consistent insertion of space characters.

Your comments like

```
//return random value from specified array
```

describe the methods that follow. That's a very good habit, to document what a method does. Only, there's a Java standard ("Javadoc") way how to format such comments, supported by many tools from the Java world. That would look like

```
/**
 * Return random value from specified array.
 * @param arr character array to draw character from
 * @return a random character from the specified array
 */
```

and a template can be generated by any decent Java IDE from your method header (e.g. in Eclipse, type "/**" and ENTER above the method header, and you get it).

### Simplifications

Instead of

```
    char numbersBool = String.valueOf(inclNumbers).toLowerCase().charAt(0);
    [...]
    if(numbersBool == 't') {
        [...]
    }
```

you can omit the complicated translation to a single character, and simply write

```
    if(inclNumbers) {
        [...]
    }
```

Your methods `randValue()` and `pickRandomValuesFromLongArray()` do the same thing: return a random character from a given character array. So, you can eliminate one of them. By the way, in the two methods, you use two different random generating classes, and I don't see a reason why.

```
    PasswordGenerator obj = new PasswordGenerator();
```

You never use that `PasswordGenerator` instance. Your IDE should have flagged that as an unused variable. As long as all you methods are static, there's no point in creating an instance, so you can simply omit that line. In other words, your solution isn't object-oriented yet.

### Logic

If the user requests a 100-character password with all components, you first create four 100-character arrays, filled with random characters of one of the four types, meaning you create 400 random characters, then you randomly draw 100 characters from the concatenated array, meaning that at least 300 of the random characters have been useless. Why not concatenate the original arrays like `lowerCaseChars` and do 100 random draws from that place?

In generatePassword(), you have

```
        System.exit(0);
```

What's good about that code part is that you check for insane conditions there and react instead of blindly running into some problems later. But you should do `System.exit(0);` if you are absolutely sure that your code will never run in a bigger context. That immediately stops any work in any other part of your bigger program just because in a single situation one password's parameters were not as expected.

The recommended way to deal with such sanity checks is to throw an `IllegalArgumentException` in this case.

You'd might to read up on exceptions before doing that transition, and be careful, there's a lot of sources talking plain nonsense about the proper usage of exceptions.

### Structure

Your code isn't object oriented. How to get there?

What is a `PasswordGenerator`? It's a thing that, once initialized and parameterized, can generate passwords, so it should have a method

```
    public String generatePassword() {
        [...]
        return result;
    }
```

In my opinion, aspects like password length and character types look like parameters of a specific `PasswordGenerator` instance, so that one instance can be parameterized to provide passwords according to one site's rules, while a second one satisfies a different site. Then you can do:

```
    PasswordGenerator siteAGenerator = 
        new PasswordGenerator(true, true, false, true, 32);
    PasswordGenerator siteBGenerator = 
        new PasswordGenerator(true, false, false, true, 16);
    [...]
    String siteAPassword = siteAGenerator.generatePassword();
    String siteBPassword = siteBGenerator.generatePassword();
```

Rules of thumb:

- Avoid the `static` keyword. That forces you to (at least syntactically) use the object-oriented approach.
- Decide what the objects are that you want to deal with. In this process, write down some descriptive sentences, and watch your usage of articles (works at least in English). "A" is a hint that the following noun might become a class, while "the" hints at an instance of such a class.
- Decide what the objects should "do", if asked for by someone outside. That translates to public methods.
- Decide which information describes a given instance, and which information will be supplied with every single usage. In my example, I made the decision that a single generator will always produce passwords along the same pattern, so you supply that pattern information when constructing the instance (and the instance holds it in private fields), and when requesting new passwords, you don't need to repeat that.

Comment: Wow, I didn't expect such a excellent and detailed response! Thank you very much! To the point, I used two different generating options to make it even more random than it could be (to be honest I don't know if it does it). I did not know about Java comment standard so again Thank You. Actually I didn't want to use OOP, since I wanted all in one class. After reviewing my code I saw that creating an object was quite useless, so I'll change it later and remove one method with random class. Also thanks to you I realize that some parts could be significantly simplified. I appreciate your answer

Comment: @ElPatronSalan You're welcome, that's what Code Review is meant to provide. Regarding OOP, I'd really encourage you to embrace that concept. From 40+ years of programming experience using lots of different paradigms, I can tell you, it's really worth it!

Comment: Hi again, I've a silly question. I've created another program - now it's about (S(NTP)) and could I get your contact info or something for you to review it? I made it a bit object oriented ;)

Comment: Also I fixed a little password generator

Comment: @ElPatronSalan I'm not into free private coaching, but always feel free to ask new questions on this site, where everybody can learn from questions and answers.